# How can I create multiple relationships between the same entities in Coredata?

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, relationship

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379907/core-data-multiple-relationships-to-same-entity/7380223?noredirect=1#comment94203761_7380223) but told to open a new question.

I  have `CountryEntity`. It has two relations.

- `capital` with a `CityEntity` destination—type one to one
- `cities` with a `CityEntity` destination— type one to many.

How I should set the inverse part. Apparently only either capital or cities can have a relation with the `CountryEntity`.

Current issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just... create the relationships, and give each one an inverse relationship. No special steps are needed. From your description,

- `capital` would have a to-one inverse called something like `capitalOf`, to indicate which `CountyEntity` the `CityEntity` is capital of. If a city is not the capital, the value of the relationship would be nil.
- `cities` would have a to-one inverse called something like `county` to indicate that the `CityEntity` is in the `CountyEntity`. This would never have a nil value.

> Apparently only either capital or cities can have a relation with the `CountryEntity`

This isn't true, or at least it's not required by Core Data.

Comment: About _This isn't true, or at least it's not required by Core Data._ Can you see my edit?

Comment: Yes. You can't have two inverses **to the same relationship**. Each relationship needs its own inverse.

Comment: #facepalm! It's the first time I putting coredata to real use. I was confusing relationship with entities...So is it correct to conclude the number of relationships should always be even?

Comment: Each relationship should have an inverse, so if you count the relationship and the inverse, it'll always be an even number.